# Endline in command line arguments

Tags: command-line-arguments

I've been asked to read a file straight from the command line, 
which will be in the format of:

```
<orders> <orders> \n <orders>...
```

I've been having trouble locating the end-line sign,
I tried using:

```
if(strcmp(argv[i], "\n") !=0){
}
```

but that didn't work at all. 
Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you "read a file from the commandline", it means that you read it from stdin. Alternatively you could define an argument as a filename which you open and read.

In principle it's possible with a modern shell to provide entire file contents as a parameter (if you get the quoting right, I guess that's what went wrong in your case), but I would call this approach at best "unusual". It's surely not very practical, neither from a user's nor from a programmer's perspective.

But maybe I don't understand your question and the `\n` in your input is a literal `\n`? Then it's clear that `"\n"` won't match it, since you have to escape the escape character like in `"\\n"` (I assume this is C).